# Convert row field names to a header csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that runs through a thousand csv files and extracts rows based on a date I specify and places them in a new csv. In this case where the DATE is equal to 10-15-2017. The resultant csv file looks like the attached image.

I want it to look like a proper csv with column header.

```
STATION, DATE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, ...
USW0003013, 10-15-2017, 36.7876, -105.6434, ...
USW0003016, 10-15-2017, 37.5456, -103.5671, ...
```

[image]

I have done some searching but have only found information on transposing from rows to columns but since I have the field names in the rows I don't think this will work.

The following is the code I use to extract rows from each csv file (over one thousand) where the DATE is 10-15-2017.

```
path = "C:/py-testing/downloads/*.csv"

for fname in glob.glob(path):

     with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
         reader = csv.DictReader(f)
         rows = [
             row 
             for row in reader
             if row['DATE'] == "2017-10-15"
         ]
     for row in rows:
         with open("C:/py-testing/output.csv", "ab") as f:
             writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
             writer.writerow([row])
```

Comment: The picture you are showing doesn't exactly look like a csv file though, values don't seem to be separated by commas. It looks more like each row is the print of a python dictionary. Could you give us a minimal working bit of the code you use so that we can work on that?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yes I will post the code that extracts the rows from each CSV to the new output csv.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason, it would probably be better to put the second `with` statement and the creation of `writer` above/outside the `for` loop. Then you could also omit the 'a' flag. There's no need to open and close the file and recreate the writer for each row. In that case, you could also just do `writer.writerow(headers)` just before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily using `pandas` module as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/py-testing/downloads/*.csv"

csv_all = []
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    csv_all.append(pd.read_csv(fname))

df = pd.concat(csv_all)
df = df.loc[df['DATE'] == "2017-10-15"]
#Choose the columns you need
df = df[['STATION', 'DATE', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE']]
df.to_csv('./csv_merged.csv')
```

Comment: I keep getting DType errors. One after another. The csv files do not all have the same header. Is this why I am getting the errors? Each csv file does have header fields of STATION, LATITUDE, and LONGITUDE, but other fields may vary depending on if data is available for that station. DtypeWarning: Columns (17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,47,55,57,67,69,71,73,75) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

Comment: That is not actually an error, it is a warning, you can safely ignore that in your case since as you have mentioned the CSV files have different columns and therefore when concating, pandas handles missing values with nulls automatically. I have edited the code a bit to help you also in selecting some of the columns.

Comment: I tested it on just two csv files where I removed every column except for the ones I specified above and it worked. I will try it now with the edited code and specify the columns I need. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped, no problem!

Comment: The Dtype warnings are still there. It does not create the csv_merged file. I also shortened the columns I need to just the four. df = df[['STATION', 'DATE', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE']]  These columns are in every csv file. However I still get Dtype warnings and it does not create the csv_merged either.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the Dtype warnings are OK to have in your case. The CSV is being written in the working directory since I haven't specified any specific directory to write it to, you can change the directory where the file is written in the df.to_csv('path_of_directory').

Comment: Yes you're correct sorry. I tried using just the four columns (Station, Date Latitude, Longitude) on a folder of 20 csv files and it did create the csv_merged file.

Then, I tried choosing all the columns I need, then running the script.  This creates a memory error:     return np.concatenate(to_concat, axis=axis)
MemoryError

I added 'print fname' to determine where the error was occurring. It happens every time after the last file name. I'm guessing there is not enough memory to create the file?

Comment: I think I can probably have it create 3 merged csv files. It does not fail when I try to merge 400 csv files. So, I will just create 3 csv files and merge them later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom headers just pass them as a second parameter to the `DictWriter` (in your case fieldnames equals to `row.keys()`).

Here is an example:

```
import csv

data = []
for i in range(10):
    data.append({'Date': '10-15-2017', 'LATITUDE': i+30})

with open('csv_with_headers.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames = ["Date", "LATITUDE"])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Output:

```
cat csv_with_headers.csv
Date,LATITUDE
10-15-2017,30
10-15-2017,31
10-15-2017,32
10-15-2017,33
10-15-2017,34
10-15-2017,35
10-15-2017,36
10-15-2017,37
10-15-2017,38
10-15-2017,39
```